# df claims a mounted sd card is almost full, but I can only see a few small files

Tags: files, mount, sd-card

I'm stumped here trying to view recordings from a car dashcam's sd card. The dashcam should've been recording continuously, and was configured to overwrite old footage with new footage. Supposedly, the sd card is almost full.
Output of df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        30G   30G  707M  98% /mnt
```

However I'm only able to see five small video files, from all the way back in August 2021.

Output of ls -Rlh:

```
.:
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 32K Jan  4  2021 DCIM

./DCIM:
total 64K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 32K Jan  4  2021 DCIMA
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 32K Jan  4  2021 DCIMB

./DCIM/DCIMA:
total 2.0G
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 300M Aug 27  2021 MOVA3505.avi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 289M Aug 27  2021 MOVA3506.avi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 302M Aug 27  2021 MOVA3507.avi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 417M Aug 27  2021 MOVA3508.avi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 372M Aug 27  2021 MOVA3509.avi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 361M Aug 27  2021 MOVA3510.avi
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    0 Aug 27  2021 MOVA3511.avi

./DCIM/DCIMB:
total 0
```

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there any way I can 'recover' the missing files?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Adding an "a" to the options for LS will show up files starting with a period. Given it is being used in a dash-cam, it is probably an MS-DOS style file system, but adding the info from say `grep sda1 /proc/self/mountinfo` to the question will not hurt.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I wasn't able to find anything by adding the a option, however the grep command might have a clue: 
`1105 66 8:1 / /mnt rw,relatime shared:601 - vfat /dev/sda1 rw,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro`.
I've done some initial poking around which suggests that the remount-ro error is thrown when something goes wrong mounting the filesystem, in which case it's remounted as read-only. However if that's what happened shouldn't I still be able to read the remaining 28G worth of data on the drive?

Comment: The grep output shows the expected "vfat". What to do next depends on if you just want to get the 28GB back or you want to recover data from the drive. If you want to get the 28GB then unmount the drive and run "fsck /dev/sda1". If you want to recover data then unmounting the drive and running "cat /dev/sda1 > backup_of_dashcam" would be the next step.